# change all values in a data frame column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large dataset of GCM data from the USGS GeoData portal. I need to convert the dataset to a form for VIC 4.2 forcing files.

Below is an image of the top of the GCM data for illustrative purposes:

[GCM dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vq5dr.png)

The temperature data is in Kelvin and I need it in Celsius for VIC 4.2.

Here is my code:

```
# Script for createing a VIC 4.2 forcing file fromd the GCM data from the USGS:GeoData Portal
#
# Read the file. File is date, precip, MaxT, MinT, wind speed for entire year 2099
df <- read.csv("/Users/CoyoteGulch/Documents/ClearCreek/data-2.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
#
# Subset the data frame and convert K to C for the VIC 4.2 forcing file
#
df.forcing <- df.forcing <- df[15:379, 2:5]
#
# Convert the temperature columns from Kelvin to Celsius
df.forcing$X.1 <- df.forcing$X.1 - 273.15
df.forcing$X.2 <- df.forcing$X.2 - 273.15
```

When I run the script I get two warnings related to the last two lines:

Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(df.forcing$X.1, 273.15) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(df.forcing$X.2, 273.15) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors

In addition all of the values in columns X.1 and X.2 are changed to "NA".

## Results from dput(df.forcing)

> dput(df.forcing)
>   structure(list(X = structure(c(2L, 211L, 116L, 50L, 2L, 88L, 
>   2L, 2L, 19L, 22L, 62L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 215L, 101L, 148L, 191L, 
>   155L, 104L, 210L, 111L, 2L, 66L, 55L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 18L, 214L, 
>   92L, 169L, 185L, 53L, 221L, 73L, 186L, 130L, 106L, 212L, 132L, 
>   89L, 2L, 216L, 140L, 167L, 135L, 125L, 223L, 188L, 225L, 2L, 
>   128L, 70L, 35L, 51L, 2L, 133L, 192L, 159L, 75L, 85L, 64L, 160L, 
>   2L, 2L, 91L, 105L, 2L, 38L, 113L, 40L, 195L, 213L, 157L, 96L, 
>   220L, 176L, 141L, 134L, 2L, 2L, 158L, 179L, 180L, 182L, 48L, 
>   2L, 2L, 147L, 24L, 227L, 39L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 36L, 230L, 139L, 172L, 
>   224L, 120L, 196L, 184L, 232L, 126L, 202L, 122L, 152L, 204L, 205L, 
>   78L, 171L, 219L, 201L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 112L, 127L, 124L, 37L, 
>   28L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 43L, 228L, 107L, 231L, 2L, 2L, 181L, 206L, 86L, 
>   136L, 129L, 208L, 15L, 25L, 143L, 2L, 93L, 199L, 49L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 41L, 2L, 2L, 103L, 10L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 173L, 115L, 
>   27L, 163L, 69L, 2L, 2L, 117L, 229L, 197L, 30L, 31L, 72L, 174L, 
>   94L, 2L, 198L, 67L, 95L, 119L, 154L, 63L, 42L, 33L, 59L, 20L, 
>   16L, 6L, 4L, 45L, 13L, 187L, 149L, 9L, 11L, 207L, 217L, 2L, 3L, 
>   74L, 54L, 32L, 2L, 123L, 137L, 164L, 58L, 190L, 161L, 178L, 203L, 
>   97L, 2L, 222L, 12L, 2L, 2L, 65L, 168L, 109L, 71L, 99L, 183L, 
>   2L, 52L, 2L, 2L, 153L, 175L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 44L, 81L, 87L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 34L, 80L, 2L, 14L, 114L, 2L, 68L, 150L, 83L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 76L, 56L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 21L, 110L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 100L, 2L, 2L, 131L, 156L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   90L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 29L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 189L, 200L, 60L, 2L, 2L, 47L, 46L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 98L, 177L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 17L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 226L, 166L, 218L, 
>   209L, 121L, 79L, 84L, 23L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 138L, 233L, 77L, 
>   146L, 165L, 61L, 57L, 142L, 162L, 170L, 118L, 82L, 2L, 194L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 26L, 2L, 145L, 108L, 234L, 151L, 193L, 102L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 144L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "0", "0.051353", 
>   "0.053209", "0.053888", "0.054528", "0.055005", "0.055404", "0.055677", 
>   "0.056041", "0.064086", "0.064302", "0.064742", "0.064869", "0.064968", 
>   "0.07201", "0.082166", "0.083413", "0.084715", "0.087467", "0.089057", 
>   "0.104912", "0.111725", "0.116734", "0.122798", "0.125993", "0.133721", 
>   "0.144416", "0.153097", "0.165308", "0.166664", "0.177209", "0.193849", 
>   "0.214523", "0.238069", "0.271792", "0.289616", "0.331024", "0.343228", 
>   "0.344858", "0.350487", "0.351759", "0.355228", "0.367228", "0.36893", 
>   "0.406118", "0.408152", "0.420082", "0.432959", "0.464128", "0.480488", 
>   "0.490894", "0.493248", "0.514367", "0.532098", "0.564334", "0.569712", 
>   "0.583656", "0.620788", "0.65201", "0.705851", "0.721604", "0.741773", 
>   "0.752651", "0.78506", "0.785896", "0.817001", "0.83608", "0.877556", 
>   "0.916531", "0.935351", "0.940131", "0.945448", "0.971146", "0.98706", 
>   "1.003", "1.119203", "1.143097", "1.147298", "1.178863", "1.180787", 
>   "1.18891", "1.209772", "1.214159", "1.214449", "1.223672", "1.278638", 
>   "1.283573", "1.291003", "1.29367", "1.296009", "1.316266", "1.317941",
>   "1.48336", "1.505952", "1.507536", "1.520051", "1.549106", "1.567124", 
>   "1.568529", "1.591836", "1.607509", "1.616776", "1.618228", "1.658783", 
>   "1.668356", "1.701482", "1.724571", "1.733679", "1.761405", "1.770481", 
>   "1.77509", "1.810844", "1.849057", "1.863717", "1.877862", "1.888823", 
>   "1.937468", "1.98256", "10.06452", "10.158648", "10.239129", 
>   "10.346543", "10.387987", "10.3915", "10.512586", "10.560392", 
>   "10.675141", "11.08884", "11.37613", "11.972711", "13.477461", 
>   "13.50885", "13.797744", "13.891509", "15.740662", "15.806064", 
>   "16.130033", "17.531771", "17.64015", "18.093937", "2.037883", 
>   "2.100556", "2.111043", "2.242924", "2.286656", "2.28742", "2.334287", 
>   "2.336922", "2.370191", "2.410635", "2.416346", "2.438619", "2.537189", 
>   "2.597875", "2.644497", "2.67492", "2.716421", "2.782552", "2.78437", 
>   "2.797231", "2.801501", "2.831995", "2.972122", "2.980867", "21.684855", 
>   "23.33168", "3.078672", "3.096159", "3.160731", "3.268467", "3.281176", 
>   "3.283479", "3.425798", "3.548023", "3.577743", "3.621364", "3.631743", 
>   "3.672817", "3.722005", "3.816642", "3.904838", "3.907431", "3.965528", 
>   "4.005818", "4.047633", "4.052677", "4.076549", "4.08356", "4.143889", 
>   "4.244564", "4.301236", "4.599807", "4.799429", "4.87456", "4.875296", 
>   "5.160412", "5.160832", "5.192636", "5.221751", "5.241645", "5.270457", 
>   "5.346045", "5.414251", "5.801967", "5.834321", "6.018086", "6.034756", 
>   "6.060279", "6.343235", "6.375944", "6.417311", "6.447439", "6.569529", 
>   "6.662778", "6.672312", "7.124838", "7.171772", "7.422026", "7.448046", 
>   "7.538418", "7.547452", "7.628211", "7.936975", "8.028339", "8.037", 
>   "8.197443", "8.217916", "8.289074", "9.113519", "9.260917", "9.393965", 
>   "9.397649", "9.887436", "pr_GFDL-ESM2M_rcp45(mm)"), class = "factor"), 
>       X.1 = structure(c(21L, 18L, 5L, 15L, 7L, 23L, 90L, 93L, 61L, 
>       73L, 96L, 109L, 122L, 92L, 100L, 30L, 67L, 79L, 94L, 88L, 
>       10L, 8L, 39L, 33L, 27L, 31L, 83L, 68L, 52L, 77L, 47L, 64L, 
>       89L, 55L, 62L, 70L, 99L, 170L, 147L, 152L, 121L, 125L, 103L, 
>       146L, 113L, 81L, 40L, 9L, 26L, 24L, 20L, 12L, 17L, 4L, 11L, 
>       37L, 59L, 105L, 116L, 53L, 51L, 75L, 54L, 56L, 58L, 65L, 
>       135L, 156L, 144L, 153L, 148L, 149L, 184L, 163L, 115L, 95L, 
>       66L, 43L, 48L, 46L, 35L, 42L, 107L, 91L, 72L, 44L, 29L, 50L, 
>       28L, 137L, 175L, 167L, 140L, 108L, 166L, 183L, 206L, 253L, 
>       229L, 179L, 150L, 84L, 102L, 78L, 120L, 141L, 143L, 118L, 
>       69L, 101L, 136L, 139L, 165L, 162L, 154L, 74L, 176L, 210L, 
>       215L, 225L, 214L, 127L, 38L, 114L, 160L, 190L, 217L, 207L, 
>       259L, 201L, 228L, 195L, 203L, 236L, 226L, 202L, 223L, 189L, 
>       182L, 196L, 222L, 270L, 245L, 252L, 250L, 192L, 209L, 238L, 
>       354L, 335L, 361L, 329L, 267L, 235L, 231L, 230L, 220L, 262L, 
>       302L, 285L, 283L, 277L, 288L, 324L, 273L, 284L, 325L, 356L, 
>       328L, 188L, 177L, 247L, 320L, 309L, 254L, 265L, 326L, 248L, 
>       185L, 213L, 293L, 278L, 304L, 294L, 308L, 298L, 275L, 344L, 
>       359L, 355L, 358L, 360L, 345L, 311L, 305L, 313L, 263L, 271L, 
>       301L, 327L, 343L, 363L, 314L, 316L, 299L, 221L, 204L, 243L,
>   216L, 258L, 279L, 334L, 303L, 297L, 246L, 295L, 260L, 312L, 
>       336L, 286L, 232L, 266L, 239L, 292L, 315L, 300L, 307L, 365L, 
>       364L, 357L, 333L, 342L, 340L, 362L, 341L, 346L, 353L, 330L, 
>       339L, 347L, 332L, 323L, 352L, 349L, 287L, 310L, 272L, 212L, 
>       291L, 282L, 331L, 306L, 319L, 350L, 337L, 318L, 274L, 257L, 
>       261L, 264L, 348L, 351L, 338L, 296L, 317L, 322L, 241L, 269L, 
>       276L, 281L, 321L, 290L, 280L, 289L, 227L, 124L, 256L, 251L, 
>       268L, 255L, 211L, 157L, 244L, 237L, 219L, 194L, 187L, 181L, 
>       142L, 112L, 111L, 164L, 205L, 249L, 233L, 208L, 178L, 123L, 
>       200L, 218L, 224L, 197L, 155L, 145L, 174L, 191L, 168L, 131L, 
>       161L, 169L, 172L, 173L, 198L, 199L, 193L, 230L, 234L, 242L, 
>       240L, 180L, 128L, 110L, 119L, 104L, 86L, 57L, 129L, 151L, 
>       159L, 158L, 171L, 186L, 134L, 80L, 2L, 19L, 6L, 45L, 41L, 
>       36L, 117L, 85L, 25L, 3L, 16L, 13L, 14L, 49L, 87L, 82L, 71L, 
>       60L, 106L, 133L, 97L, 34L, 76L, 98L, 132L, 130L, 138L, 126L, 
>       63L, 22L, 32L), .Label = c("", "259.428589", "260.156494", 
>       "260.507629", "260.720245", "261.088165", "261.511139", "261.568298", 
>       "261.803802", "262.006592", "262.60437", "262.747131", "262.898529", 
>       "263.021912", "263.498688", "263.949951", "264.095947", "264.256561", 
>       "264.33075", "264.792206", "264.813507", "264.927216", "264.98938", 
>       "265.17276", "265.516876", "265.686584", "265.807068", "266.530151", 
>       "266.809723", "267.062683", "267.197632", "267.259613", "267.396179", 
>       "267.60611", "267.6073", "267.835327", "267.986572", "268.022369", 
>       "268.045685", "268.074829", "268.095062", "268.321381", "268.331268", 
>       "268.359467", "268.52356", "268.526123", "268.528412", "268.591187", 
>       "268.820099", "268.972412", "269.051941", "269.099487", "269.107727", 
>       "269.305054", "269.396637", "269.70816", "270.227875", "270.339447", 
>       "270.488586", "270.48938", "270.513428", "270.563171", "270.613617", 
>       "270.660645", "270.729828", "270.777924", "270.830688", "271.053955", 
>       "271.123169", "271.128387", "271.444763", "271.480255", "271.642059", 
>       "271.688965", "271.715057", "271.756317", "271.791962", "271.809326", 
>       "271.868439", "271.950012", "272.044128", "272.049591", "272.098602", 
>       "272.10318", "272.213684", "272.227142", "272.278931", "272.314545", 
>       "272.336182", "272.359741", "272.594177", "272.625854", "272.699402", 
>       "272.818604", "272.927795", "273.091705", "273.229492", "273.301147", 
>       "273.336639", "273.511353", "273.602844", "273.727356", "273.76474", 
>       "273.801849", "274.048553", "274.05188", "274.441315", "274.590424", 
>       "274.631287", "274.699097", "274.878448", "274.932831", "275.061615", 
>       "275.070221", "275.141479", "275.190125", "275.31485", "275.318237", 
>       "275.55545", "275.556", "275.653137", "275.721649", "275.72525", 
>       "275.934387", "276.016174", "276.041962", "276.085602", "276.124451", 
>       "276.130249", "276.159729", "276.228668", "276.320221", "276.377441", 
>       "276.539337", "276.774384", "276.881287", "276.9198", "277.092621", 
>       "277.131958", "277.36441", "277.403442", "277.439453", "277.622528", 
>       "277.693756", "277.703644", "277.85611", "277.934784", "277.950134",
>   "278.095886", "278.174072", "278.238892", "278.255829", "278.452515", 
>       "278.462372", "278.483337", "278.953766", "279.100159", "279.153931", 
>       "279.294678", "279.317596", "279.508026", "279.537079", "279.621429", 
>       "279.999115", "280.020233", "280.314301", "280.455231", "280.756378", 
>       "280.760437", "280.800446", "280.937439", "280.959503", "281.114929", 
>       "281.257385", "281.370636", "281.552307", "281.624176", "281.831757", 
>       "282.015167", "282.031097", "282.076813", "282.382965", "282.388031", 
>       "282.481537", "282.521057", "282.834534", "283.064728", "283.151062", 
>       "283.240356", "283.414337", "283.558441", "283.581696", "283.612152", 
>       "283.621155", "283.829834", "283.894073", "284.020355", "284.103546", 
>       "284.150299", "284.248383", "284.259247", "284.612152", "285.103546", 
>       "285.119568", "285.257141", "285.374878", "285.411804", "285.506897", 
>       "285.709076", "285.804993", "286.08316", "286.122467", "286.183716", 
>       "286.318848", "286.3461", "286.359772", "286.477417", "286.607391", 
>       "286.612854", "286.700134", "286.722473", "286.901428", "286.973389", 
>       "287.097137", "287.106262", "287.131714", "287.177216", "287.442657", 
>       "287.499542", "287.500824", "287.504395", "287.63858", "287.665527", 
>       "287.748169", "287.767151", "287.796448", "288.00058", "288.007996", 
>       "288.073883", "288.123871", "288.1604", "288.160461", "288.19635", 
>       "288.253998", "288.373352", "288.509796", "288.580048", "288.594025", 
>       "288.63385", "288.70105", "288.720306", "288.749908", "288.798798", 
>       "288.799805", "288.830444", "289.061127", "289.072723", "289.236267", 
>       "289.273804", "289.345306", "289.424927", "289.446259", "289.474579", 
>       "289.492249", "289.553711", "289.646454", "289.691559", "289.805725", 
>       "289.93158", "289.949799", "290.007263", "290.026703", "290.076447", 
>       "290.087952", "290.112732", "290.32135", "290.411285", "290.476074", 
>       "290.538147", "290.558655", "290.586517", "290.59668", "290.604584", 
>       "290.740723", "290.902313", "290.90329", "291.050934", "291.055756", 
>       "291.078461", "291.208008", "291.229462", "291.285431", "291.335602", 
>       "291.444427", "291.512268", "291.533081", "291.537598", "291.575806", 
>       "291.576477", "291.598572", "291.613953", "291.615479", "291.754639", 
>       "291.758118", "291.764374", "291.771606", "291.784393", "291.923523", 
>       "291.985321", "292.100342", "292.134827", "292.165588", "292.186615", 
>       "292.27887", "292.312439", "292.316559", "292.339661", "292.381897", 
>       "292.404297", "292.545471", "292.630035", "292.858795", "292.901062", 
>       "292.959442", "293.159241", "293.160767", "293.164429", "293.167084", 
>       "293.178406", "293.202728", "293.215607", "293.227539", "293.341919", 
>       "293.386932", "293.499298", "293.499969", "293.562469", "293.573639", 
>       "293.669647", "293.714203", "293.745331", "293.789734", "293.9664", 
>       "294.072388", "294.183197", "294.280457", "294.397034", "294.428131", 
>       "294.428802", "294.471771", "294.533569", "294.546387", "294.676239", 
>       "294.817413", "294.94458", "295.06723", "295.449005", "295.520996", 
>       "295.610718", "295.675964", "295.922119", "295.93811", "295.983521", 
>       "296.814697", "296.817841", "tasmax_GFDL-ESM2M_rcp45(K)"), class = "factor"), 
>       X.2 = structure(c(20L, 29L, 5L, 8L, 14L, 16L, 26L, 81L, 72L,
>   50L, 86L, 89L, 83L, 35L, 62L, 78L, 95L, 57L, 102L, 40L, 15L, 
>       13L, 37L, 44L, 36L, 31L, 23L, 34L, 71L, 79L, 88L, 82L, 109L, 
>       103L, 56L, 124L, 92L, 159L, 216L, 127L, 130L, 98L, 58L, 110L, 
>       126L, 139L, 76L, 43L, 21L, 42L, 53L, 19L, 7L, 27L, 12L, 46L, 
>       59L, 118L, 142L, 69L, 64L, 85L, 75L, 67L, 65L, 48L, 66L, 
>       133L, 145L, 136L, 129L, 166L, 182L, 213L, 91L, 119L, 87L, 
>       25L, 52L, 96L, 61L, 45L, 106L, 115L, 55L, 47L, 33L, 30L, 
>       32L, 73L, 172L, 167L, 165L, 84L, 170L, 163L, 184L, 294L, 
>       345L, 197L, 161L, 146L, 141L, 100L, 138L, 198L, 179L, 144L, 
>       143L, 114L, 150L, 171L, 187L, 210L, 189L, 162L, 137L, 178L, 
>       205L, 186L, 225L, 134L, 112L, 123L, 169L, 212L, 180L, 233L, 
>       295L, 231L, 316L, 286L, 232L, 239L, 325L, 322L, 309L, 285L, 
>       273L, 255L, 256L, 302L, 314L, 259L, 270L, 236L, 221L, 211L, 
>       315L, 357L, 342L, 303L, 204L, 199L, 264L, 234L, 226L, 289L, 
>       328L, 310L, 288L, 312L, 293L, 257L, 274L, 290L, 268L, 247L, 
>       354L, 331L, 298L, 244L, 174L, 292L, 333L, 317L, 280L, 219L, 
>       242L, 251L, 321L, 329L, 297L, 287L, 271L, 282L, 351L, 238L, 
>       284L, 361L, 365L, 359L, 338L, 347L, 323L, 340L, 353L, 366L, 
>       304L, 301L, 305L, 356L, 346L, 281L, 349L, 364L, 348L, 245L, 
>       343L, 341L, 296L, 308L, 324L, 243L, 250L, 175L, 201L, 277L, 
>       362L, 363L, 313L, 254L, 260L, 235L, 240L, 318L, 222L, 252L, 
>       360L, 319L, 278L, 262L, 246L, 332L, 344L, 334L, 330L, 339L, 
>       335L, 358L, 248L, 214L, 190L, 275L, 230L, 237L, 326L, 336L, 
>       229L, 337L, 350L, 327L, 269L, 209L, 300L, 311L, 307L, 258L, 
>       193L, 283L, 306L, 276L, 355L, 352L, 320L, 261L, 200L, 183L, 
>       223L, 203L, 228L, 279L, 266L, 249L, 272L, 128L, 194L, 241L, 
>       207L, 220L, 218L, 101L, 125L, 267L, 173L, 121L, 202L, 120L, 
>       80L, 51L, 22L, 74L, 185L, 208L, 206L, 196L, 148L, 90L, 104L, 
>       227L, 263L, 164L, 131L, 41L, 160L, 215L, 217L, 113L, 116L, 
>       149L, 140L, 117L, 154L, 176L, 156L, 253L, 299L, 265L, 291L, 
>       191L, 224L, 152L, 151L, 188L, 157L, 63L, 111L, 153L, 147L, 
>       177L, 168L, 195L, 158L, 17L, 4L, 38L, 54L, 28L, 77L, 70L, 
>       93L, 105L, 11L, 3L, 2L, 24L, 6L, 9L, 60L, 107L, 49L, 94L, 
>       192L, 181L, 108L, 97L, 68L, 99L, 155L, 122L, 135L, 132L, 
>       39L, 10L, 18L), .Label = c("", "242.450241", "243.644272", 
>       "245.709274", "246.48465", "246.763947", "247.267105", "247.326279", 
>       "247.766083", "248.395248", "248.494522", "248.597458", "248.834702", 
>       "249.323273", "249.76535", "249.835007", "250.343948", "250.578537", 
>       "251.303207", "251.479492", "251.614716", "251.804214", "251.953949", 
>       "252.18428", "252.355881", "252.538666", "252.645538", "252.775421", 
>       "252.960327", "253.048584", "253.24826", "253.338791", "253.457031", 
>       "253.56041", "253.726425", "253.786713", "253.791046", "253.889023", 
>       "254.229935", "254.311646", "254.474426", "254.487854", "254.524155", 
>       "254.551086", "254.680969", "254.737823", "254.815369", "254.8703",
>   "254.959457", "255.129913", "255.411377", "255.422699", "255.426575", 
>       "255.442307", "255.613403", "255.897842", "255.957077", "256.045288", 
>       "256.285034", "256.29303", "256.518005", "256.522034", "256.61441", 
>       "256.936554", "256.977966", "257.088501", "257.153076", "257.211548", 
>       "257.225433", "257.255951", "257.32666", "257.356812", "257.384277", 
>       "257.432007", "257.447113", "257.522583", "257.780426", "257.836273", 
>       "257.841461", "257.889557", "258.019379", "258.020844", "258.148499", 
>       "258.205902", "258.41333", "258.635162", "258.796722", "258.945099", 
>       "259.070679", "259.078308", "259.376923", "259.395355", "259.398529", 
>       "259.570068", "259.627106", "259.673798", "259.696564", "259.821869", 
>       "259.932404", "259.96344", "260.013672", "260.070831", "260.129486", 
>       "260.324951", "260.411041", "260.432892", "260.624115", "260.641418", 
>       "260.702423", "260.745117", "260.770264", "260.845215", "260.906464", 
>       "260.99585", "261.166718", "261.22583", "261.407806", "261.511261", 
>       "261.540527", "261.565704", "261.655487", "261.801605", "261.863983", 
>       "261.870026", "262.151093", "262.196747", "262.22757", "262.249481", 
>       "262.317963", "262.340698", "262.385559", "262.387177", "262.403442", 
>       "262.479034", "262.493469", "262.531403", "262.553009", "262.557159", 
>       "262.621521", "262.857697", "262.922821", "262.941437", "263.046661", 
>       "263.061554", "263.084106", "263.091858", "263.196625", "263.377075", 
>       "263.391602", "263.419647", "263.497009", "263.562317", "263.641571", 
>       "263.643036", "263.753418", "263.789978", "263.860199", "263.893188", 
>       "263.993347", "264.045593", "264.169312", "264.245911", "264.312653", 
>       "264.341797", "264.39035", "264.71756", "264.784302", "264.820099", 
>       "264.833801", "264.957703", "264.976593", "265.048126", "265.097137", 
>       "265.130432", "265.159332", "265.204926", "265.402344", "265.412476", 
>       "265.451019", "265.461639", "265.562653", "265.712616", "265.786896", 
>       "265.810303", "265.903748", "265.925995", "266.062683", "266.158936", 
>       "266.180847", "266.264557", "266.326111", "266.365845", "266.382629", 
>       "266.45752", "266.480591", "266.486053", "266.579651", "266.669342", 
>       "266.725586", "266.97049", "267.090576", "267.243958", "267.253784", 
>       "267.366211", "267.379364", "267.440674", "267.511169", "267.68335", 
>       "267.72467", "267.789307", "267.812927", "268.062805", "268.072357", 
>       "268.12442", "268.184692", "268.295959", "268.305725", "268.30835", 
>       "268.45105", "268.607971", "268.639374", "268.654633", "268.720093", 
>       "268.844543", "268.918335", "268.976959", "268.994415", "269.022034", 
>       "269.139404", "269.14975", "269.214508", "269.231201", "269.241638", 
>       "269.307434", "269.322662", "269.529083", "269.529694", "269.646393", 
>       "269.805634", "269.824677", "269.868103", "269.965393", "270.041473", 
>       "270.046814", "270.192871", "270.195221", "270.19928", "270.423523", 
>       "270.466583", "270.467529", "270.524475", "270.536346", "270.567535", 
>       "270.613953", "270.614777", "270.666595", "270.671631", "270.717926", 
>       "270.722137", "270.750793", "270.755554", "270.768677", "270.84433", 
>       "270.846924", "270.894226", "270.905609", "271.007629", "271.064789", 
>       "271.085938", "271.196869", "271.31601", "271.321167", "271.323486",
>   "271.351471", "271.360474", "271.439789", "271.47052", "271.548126", 
>       "271.634674", "271.638489", "271.687622", "271.725372", "271.752502", 
>       "271.766022", "271.843964", "271.869934", "271.898193", "271.924469", 
>       "271.964691", "271.969116", "271.991119", "272.012878", "272.069", 
>       "272.085297", "272.093964", "272.143524", "272.215515", "272.228912", 
>       "272.241425", "272.323486", "272.358002", "272.390472", "272.404663", 
>       "272.454742", "272.464722", "272.546753", "272.567749", "272.612946", 
>       "272.621796", "272.671448", "272.810425", "272.874817", "272.881836", 
>       "272.908875", "272.916229", "272.941254", "273.020935", "273.055481", 
>       "273.061035", "273.168518", "273.175598", "273.208038", "273.269684", 
>       "273.280121", "273.283234", "273.366608", "273.411285", "273.461548", 
>       "273.480316", "273.500732", "273.510834", "273.566589", "273.618286", 
>       "273.652405", "273.833557", "273.851471", "273.858795", "273.968719", 
>       "273.984314", "274.024506", "274.133148", "274.203766", "274.302612", 
>       "274.43988", "274.5271", "274.650055", "274.66507", "275.113495", 
>       "275.201385", "275.233124", "275.405609", "275.530212", "275.708557", 
>       "275.823944", "275.892426", "275.981812", "276.591156", "276.684509", 
>       "276.701904", "276.704224", "276.716614", "277.096893", "277.565582", 
>       "277.608917", "277.876556", "280.091156", "tasmin_GFDL-ESM2M_rcp45(K)"
>       ), class = "factor"), X.3 = structure(c(321L, 358L, 322L, 
>       134L, 35L, 36L, 356L, 351L, 345L, 350L, 343L, 224L, 231L, 
>       237L, 159L, 337L, 174L, 194L, 342L, 261L, 177L, 58L, 124L, 
>       20L, 178L, 197L, 181L, 131L, 137L, 184L, 109L, 191L, 324L, 
>       326L, 279L, 305L, 277L, 352L, 330L, 325L, 320L, 346L, 313L, 
>       288L, 227L, 95L, 332L, 218L, 40L, 113L, 276L, 265L, 120L, 
>       271L, 13L, 255L, 234L, 286L, 334L, 359L, 246L, 179L, 331L, 
>       243L, 207L, 193L, 19L, 122L, 141L, 101L, 81L, 275L, 287L, 
>       316L, 354L, 269L, 304L, 306L, 18L, 285L, 315L, 240L, 314L, 
>       347L, 270L, 212L, 312L, 260L, 245L, 161L, 319L, 272L, 296L, 
>       199L, 300L, 267L, 202L, 203L, 200L, 63L, 147L, 182L, 25L, 
>       64L, 91L, 47L, 143L, 74L, 156L, 189L, 87L, 82L, 26L, 185L, 
>       289L, 249L, 9L, 85L, 158L, 229L, 65L, 348L, 311L, 89L, 100L, 
>       84L, 37L, 115L, 128L, 209L, 205L, 233L, 254L, 126L, 133L, 
>       295L, 96L, 62L, 69L, 180L, 112L, 132L, 187L, 266L, 216L, 
>       129L, 92L, 12L, 142L, 252L, 307L, 328L, 274L, 221L, 273L, 
>       140L, 7L, 60L, 106L, 67L, 22L, 17L, 11L, 4L, 57L, 86L, 168L, 
>       80L, 2L, 46L, 183L, 228L, 55L, 144L, 66L, 73L, 75L, 136L, 
>       139L, 230L, 256L, 162L, 127L, 195L, 116L, 28L, 211L, 90L, 
>       99L, 204L, 172L, 151L, 54L, 94L, 88L, 98L, 53L, 59L, 238L, 
>       108L, 76L, 56L, 118L, 71L, 103L, 253L, 68L, 10L, 49L, 33L, 
>       24L, 42L, 107L, 220L, 259L, 93L, 39L, 125L, 176L, 251L, 157L, 
>       31L, 41L, 34L, 5L, 14L, 27L, 148L, 155L, 241L, 317L, 102L, 
>       130L, 244L, 51L, 61L, 15L, 30L, 50L, 186L, 145L, 16L, 3L, 
>       70L, 169L, 170L, 236L, 173L, 111L, 105L, 198L, 299L, 297L, 
>       45L, 214L, 235L, 284L, 262L, 52L, 123L, 79L, 6L, 8L, 29L,
>   114L, 97L, 77L, 32L, 104L, 78L, 222L, 258L, 294L, 72L, 21L, 
>       146L, 278L, 336L, 349L, 353L, 192L, 188L, 190L, 219L, 248L, 
>       225L, 232L, 196L, 175L, 117L, 38L, 121L, 166L, 163L, 239L, 
>       149L, 339L, 362L, 250L, 327L, 290L, 333L, 329L, 226L, 292L, 
>       223L, 119L, 135L, 152L, 247L, 138L, 164L, 268L, 298L, 263L, 
>       291L, 213L, 257L, 301L, 201L, 43L, 110L, 167L, 150L, 215L, 
>       154L, 171L, 217L, 293L, 357L, 303L, 335L, 323L, 366L, 318L, 
>       242L, 264L, 340L, 281L, 302L, 364L, 365L, 310L, 208L, 44L, 
>       48L, 153L, 160L, 338L, 308L, 309L, 283L, 282L, 280L, 83L, 
>       23L, 206L, 341L, 355L, 363L, 344L, 361L, 360L, 165L, 210L
>       ), .Label = c("", "0.308711", "0.350223", "0.372361", "0.452661", 
>       "0.45767", "0.479223", "0.479858", "0.488678", "0.540984", 
>       "0.553972", "0.559801", "0.595979", "0.597407", "0.604566", 
>       "0.607804", "0.630534", "0.696327", "0.698581", "0.715278", 
>       "0.733811", "0.756622", "0.762836", "0.77172", "0.777379", 
>       "0.802102", "0.806659", "0.821714", "0.824061", "0.840609", 
>       "0.845821", "0.856451", "0.858722", "0.85938", "0.867877", 
>       "0.873104", "0.892109", "0.904525", "0.928946", "0.946203", 
>       "0.959495", "1.002311", "1.021418", "1.023297", "1.037279", 
>       "1.048275", "1.055439", "1.056586", "1.059789", "1.06143", 
>       "1.063491", "1.079899", "1.094815", "1.121482", "1.125445", 
>       "1.143452", "1.160864", "1.163049", "1.167696", "1.170274", 
>       "1.192181", "1.208833", "1.211959", "1.225451", "1.237958", 
>       "1.250322", "1.259518", "1.259935", "1.263898", "1.263964", 
>       "1.277447", "1.298623", "1.321834", "1.32392", "1.324736", 
>       "1.339335", "1.342976", "1.348525", "1.351808", "1.362328", 
>       "1.372775", "1.377807", "1.394196", "1.398014", "1.398644", 
>       "1.400519", "1.417643", "1.455236", "1.455315", "1.459143", 
>       "1.469553", "1.505987", "1.515236", "1.515658", "1.522127", 
>       "1.522886", "1.527687", "1.531216", "1.535414", "1.548916", 
>       "1.568295", "1.588813", "1.622946", "1.625622", "1.634475", 
>       "1.640951", "1.644255", "1.645561", "1.650438", "1.665424", 
>       "1.668692", "1.70499", "1.708779", "1.709914", "1.709997", 
>       "1.733056", "1.745636", "1.752424", "1.771438", "1.77306", 
>       "1.821715", "1.838297", "1.83878", "1.845666", "1.848649", 
>       "1.862355", "1.867811", "1.868097", "1.874687", "1.88562", 
>       "1.890376", "1.899474", "1.903634", "1.919699", "1.920466", 
>       "1.92179", "1.951546", "1.952309", "1.955059", "1.958272", 
>       "1.964074", "1.982513", "1.98741", "1.993316", "1.995707", 
>       "2.011323", "2.014163", "2.023299", "2.037455", "2.038828", 
>       "2.051759", "2.053047", "2.059833", "2.069882", "2.077679", 
>       "2.08123", "2.103823", "2.152242", "2.164339", "2.177232", 
>       "2.18944", "2.190869", "2.201279", "2.20196", "2.203591", 
>       "2.219005", "2.231235", "2.231395", "2.23396", "2.245424", 
>       "2.260555", "2.263005", "2.280839", "2.281543", "2.298646",
>   "2.316772", "2.326916", "2.332042", "2.332282", "2.340529", 
>       "2.34156", "2.387272", "2.398459", "2.419406", "2.447741", 
>       "2.449805", "2.454767", "2.455537", "2.455669", "2.460008", 
>       "2.481171", "2.491839", "2.498977", "2.511023", "2.513249", 
>       "2.514066", "2.528798", "2.540483", "2.58244", "2.597081", 
>       "2.600212", "2.623607", "2.628314", "2.634248", "2.654875", 
>       "2.659282", "2.671709", "2.684562", "2.693381", "2.696228", 
>       "2.716424", "2.720376", "2.732245", "2.733452", "2.733512", 
>       "2.735265", "2.736797", "2.739885", "2.748732", "2.750032", 
>       "2.750829", "2.75997", "2.76703", "2.787926", "2.794659", 
>       "2.818153", "2.8319", "2.832634", "2.864392", "2.864474", 
>       "2.864678", "2.864762", "2.865481", "2.871558", "2.872001", 
>       "2.886446", "2.895627", "2.912665", "2.939761", "2.939846", 
>       "2.940798", "2.946666", "2.9572", "2.98643", "3.002297", 
>       "3.00517", "3.056561", "3.058981", "3.060029", "3.077511", 
>       "3.082538", "3.095381", "3.110173", "3.127519", "3.156171", 
>       "3.166575", "3.194167", "3.198972", "3.230315", "3.233357", 
>       "3.234677", "3.279899", "3.292216", "3.29559", "3.322748", 
>       "3.325321", "3.365275", "3.370972", "3.402015", "3.402179", 
>       "3.404078", "3.406688", "3.431145", "3.434803", "3.530465", 
>       "3.546225", "3.568231", "3.595263", "3.596859", "3.621116", 
>       "3.662884", "3.68073", "3.686013", "3.686079", "3.700039", 
>       "3.709341", "3.71924", "3.731145", "3.780532", "3.832445", 
>       "3.849474", "3.854805", "3.862742", "3.897382", "3.921543", 
>       "3.921577", "3.938214", "3.942264", "3.942419", "3.945301", 
>       "3.973213", "3.974383", "4.001139", "4.016488", "4.030596", 
>       "4.031099", "4.031496", "4.044111", "4.057593", "4.074", 
>       "4.099645", "4.100109", "4.107349", "4.110504", "4.173357", 
>       "4.180363", "4.189736", "4.203447", "4.251505", "4.262193", 
>       "4.274528", "4.299968", "4.313471", "4.333906", "4.362791", 
>       "4.365851", "4.376681", "4.378855", "4.399515", "4.408618", 
>       "4.447083", "4.478985", "4.540248", "4.547806", "4.589968", 
>       "4.596299", "4.616023", "4.659328", "4.678977", "4.768427", 
>       "4.776873", "4.787859", "4.816487", "4.890985", "4.902739", 
>       "5.013013", "5.027411", "5.034097", "5.037682", "5.068965", 
>       "5.088162", "5.096173", "5.147941", "5.168827", "5.171349", 
>       "5.328141", "5.365369", "5.38986", "5.399864", "5.428233", 
>       "5.514956", "5.62412", "5.74389", "6.545115", "6.747962", 
>       "7.099587", "was_GFDL-ESM2M_rcp45(ms-1)"), class = "factor")), row.names = 15:379, class = "data.frame")

Comment: Please dont put such huge data as part of question. You should try to provide either a reproducible example for your problem. May be `dput(head(df.forcing, 20))` would be good enough to understand problem.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All columns of `df.forcing` are `factor`s.

```
str(df.forcing)
#'data.frame':  365 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ X  : Factor w/ 235 levels "","0","0.051353",..: 2 211 116 50 2 88 2 2 19 22 ...
# $ X.1: Factor w/ 366 levels "","259.428589",..: 21 18 5 15 7 23 90 93 61 73 ...
# $ X.2: Factor w/ 367 levels "","242.450241",..: 20 29 5 8 14 16 26 81 72 50 ...
# $ X.3: Factor w/ 367 levels "","0.308711",..: 321 358 322 134 35 36 356 351 345 350 ...
```

Convert to `numeric` with

```
library(dplyr)
df.forcing <- mutate_all(df.forcing, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
str(df.forcing)
#'data.frame':  365 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ X  : num  0 6.376 1.878 0.464 0 ...
# $ X.1: num  265 264 261 263 262 ...
# $ X.2: num  251 253 246 247 249 ...
# $ X.3: num  4.275 5.39 4.3 1.92 0.868 ...
```

Then convert from Kelvin to Celsius as before.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I would never have come up with the fix in a million years. I appreciate it. I hope to be able to determine what is going on with the code by looking at the documentation for dplyr.

Comment: @JohnOrr I'm happy to help:-) f you found the answer useful and it answers your question, please upvote and mark as Accepted by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'm new to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have read from your csv file with strings as factors.

Try using this to read your data, so the values stay numeric

```
df <- read.csv("/Users/CoyoteGulch/Documents/ClearCreek/data-2.csv", 
               header = TRUE, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It did not work however: Error in df.forcing$X.1 - 273.15 :  non-numeric argument to binary operator